# Python function annotation: specify possible parameter types with | (or)

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, pycharm

I want to use function annotations in Python 3 to specify parameter types, for TypeHinting in PyCharm (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html).

This works, but not if I have more than one possible type for one parameter. PyCharm help suggests the use of | (or) in this case, and I recall that I have seen this elsewhere as well. My definition looks like this:

```
def derive_psd(data: numpy.ndarray, sampling_rate: int | float) -> (numpy.ndarray, float):
```

When I try to import this function I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type'
```

Apparently Python compiler does not like the pipe, but what would be the right way to specify two possibilites for types? How would I specify a default value in such a case (e.g. `None`)?

Comment: Have you tried just using the keyword `or` instead of `|`?

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo! Exchanging | by or did the trick. Now it is working fine.

Comment: @MattDMo : you should write an answer and vote it as accepted. I was considering doing it, but its yours.